# Keycloak update user locale after login

Tags: cookies, keycloak

I need to update a locale user attribute, once he is connected with **Keycloak** **(6.0.1)**. I have a SpringBoot app and an angular front-end application.

I tried to use a back-end API to update my locale user attribute, or to modify it in the Keycloak admin interface, and it works, but when I reload my page (F5), my change is reset.

I know there is a specific order used by keycloak to set the locale :

1. **kc_locale** parameter
2. **KEYCLOAK_LOCALE** cookie
3. ***UserModel attribute***

I think I know what's happen :

1. The kc_locale parameter is set at login (I can use default locale at login)
2. Once connected, the KEYCLOAK_LOCALE cookie is set, and his value corresponding to the kc_locale. My locale user attribute is also updated with this kc_locale value.
3. After that, if I try to update my user locale attribute, and it works, but it not update the KEYCLOAK_LOCALE cookie, so after the next reload of my page, my locale attribute seems to be overwritten by the value in the cookie. When I manually change the value of the cookie, it works.

So, my question : is it possible to update the KEYCLOAK_LOCALE cookie value with the new one, OR only use the locale attribute to specify the language user, without using SPI ?